# Who are the parents of Taweret?

Tags: egyptian

Taweret is arguably one of the most popular goddesses of the Egyptian pantheon. Although much about her consorts is known, nothing is said about the Hippo Goddess' parentage and I would like to find out about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is surely the daughter of Ra. Not sure who the mother could be. But that the same with Sekhmet. Another daughter of Ra without a defined mother. Chance for the mother could roll on Hathor, you often find Hathor and Taweret together, but considering Hathor could also be Ra's daughter... Or Heset which is more or then Ra's traditional wife. Ra's spouse is so an incredibly unsure topic.